# How to remove NSTableView's border and change cell selection color as same as Finder's?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm making an Cocoa app for Yosemite.

I added a view based NSTableView in Interface builder, but the border 2 pixel width and thicker than Yosemite's Finder's.
And the cell selection color is blue, while Yosemite's Finder's is gray.

[image]

[image]

And this is how Yosemite's Finder's table view looks like.

[image]

I checked the settings in Interface Builder.
The super scroll view of NSTableView's frame setting is (0,0,149,257):
[image]

While the Clip View's frame setting is (1, 1, 147, 255) and can not be changed.

[image]

And how to make a same NSTableView as Yosemite's Finder's?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Notice the description of your scroll view: "**Bordered** Scroll View - Table View". Check the attributes of the scroll view and turn off the border. The 1-pixel divider is probably from the split view.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Finder sidebar isn't a table-view it's a *Source List* `NSOutlineView`:

[image]

The border is applied around the enclosing scroll view:

[image]

Note also that a standard `NSOutlineView` lets you adjust the highlight style from within Interface Buider:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience selected rows are still painted blue, even when the "Source List" highlight style is selected. To avoid that, I needed to prevent the table or outline view from becoming the first responder by subclassing it and adding

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

**Edit:**
Turns out `becomeFirstResponder` is actually important if you want to support keyboard navigation. I have found a better solution that does not override `becomeFirstResponder`.

First, create a custom `NSTableRowView` subclass with an (overridden) empty `setEmphasized:` method:

```
- (void)setEmphasized:(BOOL)emphasized {
    // This avoids a blue background when selected in a source list that has first responder status.
}
```

You can then provide an instance of your custom `NSTableRowView` class by implementing

```
- (NSTableRowView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowViewForRow:(NSInteger)row
```

in your `NSTableViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever wants to remove the NSTableView border...

My requirement was to remove the border colour of the NSTableView so that, it should look like a white box. Tried all properties and forums but couldn't find a way to do that. Finally I came up with a dirty hack in the Storyboard which could fix the problem. If someone have a better option, please let us know.

1. Embed the NSTableView in a CustomBox. Set the Box BorderType as 'None'
2. Then set the constraints (Left, Top, Right and Bottom) of NSTableView to the containing Box. Set the values to `-2`. so that the NSTableView border will be outside of the Box
3. Now in Storyboard, select the 'clipView(NSClipView)' of the NSTableView. clipView is the superView of the NSTableView
4. Go to the Size Inspector and uncheck the 'Automatically Adjust' property of the "Content Insets"
5. Set the values to `Left=2`, `Top=2`, `Bottom=-2` and `Right=-2`

Thats it.